# Nested functions in closure not being called properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

I am new to Javascript and learning about closures and nested scope.

The prompt asks for this:
Write a function that has three nested functions, each taking one number as an argument. The inner-most function should return the sum of all three numbers.

This is what I have come up:

```
var outMost = function (num1) {
var x = num1;
var innerMost = function (num2) {
    var y = num2;
    var innerInnerMost = function (num3) {
        console.log(x + y + num3);
    }
    return innerInnerMost;
}
return innerMost;
}

var firstNum = outMost(1);
firstNum(2);
firstNum((3));
```

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong -- I have gone on numerous website to learn about closures and scope but nothing seems to explain it well. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Notice that the `x` and `y` variables are not necessary, the `num1` and `num2` named parameters are variables in the same scopes that you could simply use directly for the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `firstNum(2)`, you are not catching the return-value (which is a function).  If I run your code in Node.js REPL, here is what it looks like:

```
> var firstNum = outMost(1);
undefined
> firstNum(2);
[Function]
> firstNum((3));
[Function]
```

Try this in the end instead:

```
var firstNum = outMost(1);
var secondNum = firstNum(2);
secondNum(3);
```

Here is what it looks like in Node.js REPL:

```
> var firstNum = outMost(1);
undefined
> var secondNum = firstNum(2);
undefined
> secondNum(3);
6
undefined
```

Please note that assignment evaluates to `undefined`.  Also, since innerInnerMost doesn't `return` anything, there is an implicit `return undefined` in the end.

Comment: Thank you very much Harry -- makes more sense now.

Comment: I did, can you please give my question a couple points. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
function firstFunc(x){
    return function secondFunc(y){
            return function thirdFunc(z){
                    console.log(x+y+z);
                }
        }
}
```

**Calling:**

```
var ff = firstFunc(1);

var sf = ff(2);

sf(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

very easy **look** at this example

if you have this type 
in **ES6**

```
  let f = () => {
  return () => {
    console.log('First function called');
    return () => {
      console.log('Second function called');
    }
  }
}
```

you have two way to call every function, first of all, I want to call the **First** function 
in this way `f()()` and then I want to call the **Second** function f()()().
First of all, you will be seeing in console

> *First function called*

and then

> *Second function called*

and another way you can use this technic

```
let f1 = f();
let f2 = f1();
```

you will be seeing

> First function called

if you want to the second function call

```
let f1 = f();
let f2 = f1();
let f3 = f2();
```

and then you will be seeing

> Second function called

if you want to change this code to **ES5**

```
var f = function() {
  return function() {
    console.log('First function');
    return function(){
      console.log('Second function');
    }
  }
}
```

two way of call

```
var f1 = f();
var f2 = f1();
var f3 = f2();

f()()();
```